# Ionic scrollTo skips top value. What is __maxScrollTop? Possible bug

Tags: javascript, cordova, scroll, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-scroll` and i want to scroll to a certain point.

```
<ion-scroll
    id="mapScroll"
    zooming="true" 
    direction="xy" 
    min-zoom="1" 
    scrollbar-x="false" 
    scrollbar-y="false" 
    overflow-scroll="false"
    delegate-handle="mapScroll"
    has-bouncing="false"
    >
    <div ng-include="'./img/map/map.svg'"></div>
</ion-scroll>
```

In the controller I scroll to [left, top points](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/):

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mapScroll').scrollTo(359, 619);
```

Left scroll works but no top one, I debugged and I found in ionic.js #6139 this line:

```
top = Math.max(Math.min(self.__maxScrollTop, top), 0);
```

Where top parameter is 619 but as `self.__maxScrollTop` is 0 top var but ends with 0. What is `self.__maxScrollTop`?

`ion-view`, `ion-content`, `ion-scroll` has a valid height value. `html` and `body` didn't have I set `height: 100%` but nothing changed.

Is this an ionic bug or do I have a way to fix it?

[image]
[image]

P.S: I have ionic v1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

No bug at all.

From [ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/)

> Note that it’s important to **set the height of the scroll box** as well
>   as the height of the inner content to enable scrolling. This makes it
>   possible to have full control over scrollable areas

```
<ion-scroll style="height: 100%;">
```